# Chatter post as site guest user

Tags: api, site.com

I have open API that external application use through site.com
In this case, API logic runs as site guest user.

The problem is,
Site guest user has no permission to post chatter.
However, I need to post feed in API logic.

Is there any workaround?
If I wrote trigger posting chatter feed, and invoke this trigger in API apex code, would it work?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cant access Chatter with Guest User Content. No matter what you do, if you are in Guest user content you will never be able to post to chatter

Fortunately there are 2 solutions for it on top of my head

1) **Using Platform Event** : Guest user can publish platform events. YAY. So you just have to Write a trigge on platform Event that will insert a FeedItem(Chatter)

2) **Using Rest API**: Store a system user's Username and password in CUstom Settings / Custom Metadata and then Use that to get Acces Token using username-password oauth flow. Once you got access token you can directly call chatter rest endpoint to post messages.

Comment: or -- use a ProcessBuilder as Platform Event subscriber ..could be faster to set up

Comment: Thanks Pranay and cropredy.
Currently, I cannot use user authentication way, so, looks like I need to approach with Platform Event.

If guest user generate platform event, and trigger catch the event and create chatter post, this post is created by System not by Guest user?

Comment: I created trigger and post chatter feed in there.
Guest user just modify another normal field for firing Platform Event.

However, the same error occurs.
'Guest users are not permitted to perform this operation.'

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, it migth work:

Site guest user creating a Custom Platform Event, Trigger (NOT PB) listening to it:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317184&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1