# Process builder's Post to Chatter error

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, chatter, chatter-feed, chatter-groups

In Process builder, I have a Post to Chatter action. When this action gets triggered, I am getting error message and exception is thrown. I have attached the error line from debug logs: `FLOW_ACTIONCALL_DETAIL|9086c181606dd98184557174ae5116d63ba0a-8282|myRule_1_A1|Post to Chatter|chatterPost|false|Guest users are not permitted to perform this operation.`

We have gues user with the profile license 'Guest User License'.

Here is the screenshot of the Post to Chatter in Process builder:[image]

Comment: Error log is pretty straight forward and self-explanatory. You need to enable guest user profile with the necessary accesses.

Comment: the gues user profile is already enabled. What access should be given to the user?

Comment: Have you tried Googling? I found this: [Guest users cant post on Chatter](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000keDRAAY). Also, from this [solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252089/chatter-post-as-site-guest-user), you might need to go in a different route to post to chatter from a Guest user profile.

Answer (score 0):

If your flow is being triggered by a Guest User, you need to enable public access.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_public_access.htm&type=5

Comment: The user's profile has the 'Guest User License'. So there is no Create and Set Up Communities setting.